# symfony2, form builder, how to initially display an empty entity select list

Tags: symfony, twig

I have 3 entities: Make, Model and Auto.  Make -> Model is oneToMany relation and Auto->Model is manyToOne relation.

What I want to achieve is to be able to generate a form that consist of list of Makes e.g Ford, Opel.. and initially load an empty list of Models.  The Model list should be populated only when a Make is selected in the list, that is achieved by ajax call.

My question is what I need to do that Model list is initially empty since the form builder is populating with all models that are asigned in any Make.

I can achieve similar by using query_builder and let say search for a model that does not exist, but that's not the wright way.

```
class AutoType extends AbstractType {
   public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) { 
       $builder->add('make','choice', array(
                   'choices'=>Array('1'=>'Opel', '2'=>'Ford'),
                   'property_path'=>false,
                   'label'=>'Make'))
                ->add('model', 'entity', array(  // this fetches all models.  Also don't want a subset of models, just empty list with 'Select Model' 
                 'class' => 'Auto\SalonBundle\Entity\Model',
                 'empty_value' => 'Select Model'
                  ))
                ->add('km')
                ->add('cc')
                ->add('hp')
                ->add('kw')
          );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that you have to create your own Form Type and corresponding _widget block. Or you can get there faster using the Dependent Filtered Form Type of the bundle https://github.com/shtumi/ShtumiUsefulBundle .

Comment: Actually, I ended up passing down a parameter 'make' to the AutoType and used query_builder to load a subset of models. To achieve the empty list, initially I pass down a non existent Make so the list of Models is initially displayed empty. Only when Make is selected then Model list is populated. It works, and for time being I am leaving it like that. I will check out your suggestion at a later time and thank you for your effort put on the question.